# Does an electron have a frequency (and hence an energy)?

Tags: energy, electrons, fermions, dispersion

The formulation is provocative, the question is similar to the [question here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156966/why-dont-the-de-broglie-dispersion-relation-contain-a-constant-term). There I can follow the question, but not the answers, which for me imply that an electron in a momentum eigenstate does not have a certain energy.

In other words again: in Wikipedia and many textbooks you can find the dispertion relation
$$
\omega (k)=\frac{\hbar k^2}{2m}
$$
which is a consequence of the Schrödinger equation 
$$
-{\frac  {\hbar ^2}{2m}}\nabla ^{2}\ \psi (r,t)=i\hbar {\frac  {\partial }{\partial t}}\psi (r,t)
$$
for free particles if you set 
$$
p=\hbar k,\quad E=\hbar \omega 
$$
On the other hand the relativistic dispersion relation is
$$
\omega (k)=\sqrt{ k^2 c^2 + \frac{1}{\hbar^2} m^2 c^4  }
$$
The non-relativistic approximation with $ k^2 c^2 \ll \frac{1}{\hbar^2} m^2 c^4 $
then is , because $ \sqrt{1+x} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} x + O(x^2) $ , 
$$
\omega (k) \simeq \frac{mc^2}{\hbar} + \frac{\hbar k^2}{2m}
$$
which differs from the first equation by a term also known as Compton frequency.

So my question is: Is the first equation a wrong approximation?
Or a different formulation would be: is it true that there is no experiment that can detect an electron's frequency (hence energy)? Only wavelengths can be observed like in the double slit experiment?
Or in a more philosophical way: Does an electron **have** a frequency if there is no experiment that can detect it?

If the first equation is wrong, shouldn't the usual Schrödinger equation in position base read
$$
i\hbar {\frac {\partial }{\partial t}}\Psi (\mathbf {r} ,t)=\left[{\frac {-\hbar ^{2}}{2\mu }}\nabla ^{2}+V(\mathbf {r} ,t)+mc^2\right]\Psi (\mathbf {r} ,t)
$$
yielding the correct non-relativistic limit for the frequency when setting 
$$
\lambda(p) = \frac{h}{p}, \quad \omega(p) = \frac{p^2}{2m\hbar} + \frac{mc^2}{\hbar}
$$
rather than
$$
i\hbar {\frac {\partial }{\partial t}}\Psi (\mathbf {r} ,t)=\left[{\frac {-\hbar ^{2}}{2m}}\nabla ^{2}+V(\mathbf {r} ,t)\right]\Psi (\mathbf {r} ,t)
$$
The last equation has solutions with negative energies when introducing an attracting force $ V(r) $ like in the hydrogen problem. With $ mc^2 $ you get purely positive energy eigenvalues which better fits to a relationship of energy and measurable information, the latter one being positive by definition and limited by the dimension of the Hilbert space, which itself  is positive by definition.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, you give a formulation for finding the energy and frequency of an electron and ask if it exists.

Comment: See the [linked question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156966/why-dont-the-de-broglie-dispersion-relation-contain-a-constant-term) and there the comments "So you can just redefine energy by removing this value and take energy levels by referring to the constant term as the 0-energy level" and "A constant energy term will affect nothing since only energy differences are physically meaningful." They argue that energy has no physical meaning. But I say that it has a meaning, and the usual forms of the non-relativistic Schrödinger equation and dispertion relation are not correct.