Path Integral to Schrodinger equation using Divergence Theorem
Is it possible to derive schrodinger equation from the Path integral using an appropriate conservation law and Divergence theorem? I ask this question because I am currently taking a course where PDEs are being derived from mass conservation and Divergence theorem.

you can derive it from the Dirac equation easily enough in the nonrelativistic limit

"Is it possible to derive schrodinger equation from the Path integral..." Yes. See the book by Feynman and Hibbs titled "Quantum Mechanics and Path Integrals." In particular, section 4.1 "The Schrodinger Equation." In particular, Eq. 4.12.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142169/2451 and links therein.
